# Link to Tag broken when "+" is embedded in tag

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, tags, hyperlinks

A new tag was added for `asp.net+vb.net` in StackOverflow.  If you click on the link/tag, you don't actually see the correct results.

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net%2bvb.net

Comment: Like that? I don't quite understand from your link

Comment: Wow, that is really broken. You can't add a "+" to the URL either, so how is it possible to find the question with that broken tag?

Comment: I'm guessing this is true for other characters as well, just didn't try to find them...

Comment: @mmyers, I'm sure Jeff can just look in the database.. but this is definitely a bug

Comment: there won't be many other characters that break like this; "+" is special to the URL syntax.  note if it was "++" you could get the right tag; it's the single "+" that isn't working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net%2b%2bvb.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 tags = Regex.Replace(tags, @"(?<=[0-9a-z])\+(?=[0-9a-z])",
       " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Will be deployed later. For your viewing pleasure and my future reference, a list of all tags containing a plus:

```
++
a+
aac+
accelerated-c++
ajax+hebrew
alt+space
b+tree
blitz++
c++
c++0x
c++1x
c++builder
c++builder-2007
c++builder-2009
c++builder-2010
c++-builder-5
c++builder-5
c++builder-6
c++cli
c++-cli
c++-concepts
c++-faq
c++filt
c++-mode
c++-standard-library
c++-streams
c++test
c-c++-mixup
cc++usersjournal
checkbox+table
c-not-c++
cocoa+checkbox+tableview
column+name
com+
crypto++
c-vs-c++
dev-c++
effective-c++
flash+mysql+php
formview+mode
g++
gdi+
git+ssh
gtk+
hfs+
iphone+post
iphone+uiwebview
j++
java+smack+xmpp
jvm+msil
lapack++
lazy-c++
learning-c++
libstdc++
mac+setup
managed-c++
managed-c++opengl
modern-c++
msql-connector-c++
mysql++
n+1
n+1-selects-problem
notepad++
objective-c++
open-c++
php+javascript
php+regex
project+
py++
s+
spy++
ssl+python+stomp
svn+ssh
tinyxml++
to-be-wikified+1
turboc++
unittest++
unresolved-externals-c++
vc++
vc++.net
vc++6.0
vc++-project-file
visual+studio
visual-c++
visual-c++-2005
visual-c++-2008
visual-c++-2008-express
visual-c++-2010
visual-c++-redistributabl
windows-6+
x++
xl-c++
xml+flash+actionscript
xslt+excel
y2k+10
```

Just the problem tags

```
ajax+hebrew
asp.net+vb.net
b+tree
checkbox+table
cocoa+checkbox+tableview
column+name
flash+mysql+php
formview+mode
git+ssh
iphone+post
iphone+uiwebview
java+jsp
jvm+msil
mac+setup
n+1
php+javascript
php+regex
ssl+python+stomp
svn+ssh
to-be-wikified+1
visual+studio
xml+flash+actionscript
xslt+excel
```

<s>Yes, some of these need to be fixed as well.. working on it.</s> These should all be properly split now.