# How can I create a tag that contains "+"?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I tried to create a tag on SO that contained a plus character ("+"), but instead two separate tags were passed in. How can I create a tag that contains "+"?

Comment: My previous reply was wrong Sanoj, I apologize.. of course + is allowed, there are tags like c++. But you are right it doesn't let you create one. Weird.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43681/link-to-tag-broken-when-is-embedded-in-tag for why "++" works but "+" doesn't

Comment: Connect them with a hyphen.

Comment: @KennyTM: I actually want a + for use in b+tree, because b-tree is something different.

Comment: @Jonas Use something more descriptive. If you were to use `b+tree` when there's already a `b-tree` (and a few/several other tags along those lines), then people *will* be confused and use the wrong tag, or use both tags. Yes, you could put the information in the tag excerpt, but people commonly don't read those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`b-tree` is the tag for both, b-tree and b+ tree. You do not need an extra tag for it. You explain in your question that it is a b+ tree, that's sufficient.

No-one clicking with **"oh, a b-tree question, I can answer this!"** in mind will be scared away with **"Aaaah, b+! The evil master! Run, run!"** after reading the question text.

There are already several questions which do exactly that (using `b-tree` for b+ trees, not scaring their readers away).

Comment: Fair enough, this is what I ended up with and did.

Answer (score 7):

> @Sanoj wrote:
>   *I actually want a + for use in b+tree, because b-tree is something
>   different*

Here's a workaround:

`b-plus-tree`

Comment: this is what I recommend, if the distinction is so important. we don't allow plus in the middle of tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create tags with a plus in the middle, because .. well, just look:

http://example.com/questions/tagged/b+tree

is that questions tagged [b] and [tree]?

Incidentally, that's why when *any* tag contains a plus (we only allow it at the end) you must (and our system does) delimit tags in URLs with a space.

Comment: That's not (no longer?) true. See [tag:c++11].

Answer (score -1):

If you're creating new tags, you're probably doing something wrong.  99% of the time or more you should be using existing tags.  It's *extremely* rare to have a question that covers a completely new topic area.

Comment: I agree, but this is not an answer to my question.