# Please kill the [b+-tree] tag and maybe synonymize to [b-tree]

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request

There are 19 questions tagged as [b+-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/b%2B-tree/info), which of course won't be accessible from the tag page of [b+-tree](/questions/tagged/b%2b-tree), because it is interpreted as "[b](/questions/tagged/b) but not [tree](/questions/tagged/tree)".

According to [How can I create a tag that contains "+"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45353/how-can-i-create-a-tag-that-contains) the solution is to use the [b-tree](/questions/tagged/b-tree) tag instead.

I can find 17 of them [from the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/77612/posts-which-contains-the-b-tree-tag) but there are 2  missing.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym3Iw.png]

Comment: OK I found the remaining two with http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+[b%2B-tree].

Comment: Heh I was trying to find a way to get them but I kept running out of search queries in my 60 second timeframe. Interestingly, the [Top Users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/b%2b-tree/topusers) and other tabs on that page *say* they're searching for "b but not tree" even though it's actually searching for "b+-tree"

Comment: Ahem, isn't there really such a thing as a [b+-tree?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree)  And isn't it significantly different from a [b-tree?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)  Why didn't you guys just create a b-plus-tree tag, and synonymize b+-tree to it?

Comment: Oh, and this isn't a real blacklist request. Blacklists are dev only, and should be reserved for [really-harmful-meta-tag-thats-completely-useless].

Comment: @Robert: According to the linked question, they are similar enough to use the same tag.